# Java JSON Object Flattening

Tags: java, json

I am looking for a Java library to convert my domain objects into a flattened JSON

eg.

```
public class Person {
   String name
   Address homeAddress
}

public class Address {
  String street
  String zip
}

JSON: {name:'John', homeAddress_street: '123 Street', homeAddress_zip: 'xxxxx'}
```

I've looked into XStream, Eclipse MOXy, FlexJSON, JSON-lib & gson

My goal is to get rid of my json wrapper classes and minimize code.  I would like to have a general service that would take any domain model class I have and get a json representation without having to write xml descriptors or any custom converters for each type of model. A depth of 1 level deep is sufficient for my models. I have not found an easy generic solution using annotations or built in functionality in the above libraries but I have probably overlooked them. Is there a non intrusive library that can do this? or maybe one that I've listed? I'm using Hibernate so the library must be able to deal with CGLib Proxies

Comment: How would you flatten an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is an example of how this could be done with MOXy by leveraging the `@XmlPath` extension.

**Person**

```
package forum7652387;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {
    String name;

    @XmlPath(".")
    Address homeAddress;
}
```

**Address**

```
package forum7652387;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {
    @XmlElement(name="homeAddress_street")
    String street;

    @XmlElement(name="homeAddress_zip")
    String zip;
}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum7652387;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"homeAddress_street\":\"123 Street\", \"homeAddress_zip\":\"xxxxx\"}";
        StreamSource jsonSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(jsonString));
        Person person = unmarshaller.unmarshal(jsonSource, Person.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
 {"name" : "John", "homeAddress_street" : "123 Street", "homeAddress_zip" : "xxxxx"}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html

Comment: What if a `Person` had both a `homeAddress` and a `workAddress`?

Comment: @TomAnderson - I have entered an enhancement request to support this use case.  Please feel free to add additional details:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/376632

Comment: I think you've said everything about it that needs to be said!

Comment: Is it possible to use reflection with Moxy to accomplish this without annotating every single field in each class?

Answer (score -1):

I've used GSON very briefly and I *think* it does what you're looking for.  While investigating it, I knocked up the following ludicrously simple example to confirm it was as simple as I needed; first, a POJO:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Member {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> stuff;

    public Member() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge( int age ) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<String> getStuff() {
        return stuff;
    }

    public void setStuff( List<String> stuff ) {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

}
```

Then, the worker class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.execute( args );
    }

    private void execute( String[] args ) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Member member = new Member();

        List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
        stuff.add( "shoes" );
        stuff.add( "hat" );
        member.setStuff( stuff );
        member.setName( "Bert" );
        member.setAge( 21 );

        String output = gson.toJson( member, Member.class );
        log( output );

        Member member2 = gson.fromJson( output, Member.class );
        log(member2.getName());
    }

    private void log( String text ) {
        System.out.println( text );
    }

}
```

No xml descriptors or custom converters needed.  Is this the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: how does it flatten the model? your example model is not composed of any other domain objects